# Reposition Magento's admin grid column at first position

Tags: magento

To reposition Magento's admin grid column in custom module in child grid class we use

```
$this->addColumnsOrder($columnTobeRepostionedID,$afterColumnID);
```

But How to place a column at first position, right after  massaction checkbox column?

I tried this code but it did not work

```
$this->addColumnsOrder($columnTobeRepostionedID,'massaction');
```

So how can i position a column at first position without modifying core Grid class or using `local/Mage/Adminhtml` structure to make core Grid class ineffective

Answer (score 0):

After your code that modifies column order

```
$this->addColumnsOrder($columnTobeRepostionedID,'massaction');
```

try calling the column sorter one more time

```
$this->sortColumnsByOrder();
```

Comment: This does extra line doesn't seems to help. I tried with fresh magento installation as well. Instead of massaction if I use any other column ID from grid then first line is enough to get desired result. I'm working on shipment grid, could you please try on shipment grid to check that your code works for you or not?